# how to get connected to a question?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Suppose I want to get notified about any activity i.e. answer or comment on particular question that's not posted by me, then how do I do so.

Comment: Marking it as a favorite will do what you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you @JorgeCastro I did't find the question when I searched maybe I had typed in the wrong keyword.